# How do I change my UI's picturebox and its coordinates using a class in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 3 pictureboxes for enemy1, enemy2, and enemy3, I already coded it's images and its coordinate on the main form but when I tried to put it in a class it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Thats because your class doesnt know the Variables and MainForm. Most of the time when needing to set any Form related stuff that happens inside the Form class itself but for bigger Projects that ofcourse can get confusing. It would be easier to understand your code structure if you would share your current code.
But most likely you created your class inside the MainForm, if so you can parse the MainForm as a parameter in your classes constructor:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    MyClass myClass;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myClass = new MyClass(enemy1, enemy2, enemy3);
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    PictureBox enemy1;
    PictureBox enemy2;
    PictureBox enemy3;

    public MyClass(PictureBox penemy1, PictureBox penemy2, PictureBox penemy3)
    {
        enemy1 = penemy1;
        enemy2 = penemy2;
        enemy3 = penemy3;
    }

    public void SetPositionEnemy1(int x, int y)
    {
        enemy1.Location = new Point(x, y);
    }
}
```

I didn't test this so hopefully this is what you looked for. If something is wrong I can give you further advice.